# Eureka Discovery service on AWS ECS Fargate

Tags: spring, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ecs, netflix-eureka

I am trying to deploy microservices via ECS Fargate. I am Using Eureka as Discovery Service.
The clients are registered at eureka, but can't comunicate.

First I tried to get the IP in this way

```
  @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils){
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);
        String ip = null;
        try {
            ip = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        config.setNonSecurePort(8090);
        config.setIpAddress(ip);
        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
        return config;
    }
```

This solution throws an Connection refused Exception.

My next try was to replace the ip with the url of the loadbalancer.

```
  @Bean
    @Autowired
    public EurekaInstanceConfigBean eurekaInstanceConfig(InetUtils inetUtils){
        EurekaInstanceConfigBean config = new EurekaInstanceConfigBean(inetUtils);

        config.setNonSecurePort(8090);
        config.setIpAddress(LOADBALANCER_URL);
        config.setPreferIpAddress(true);
        return config;
    }
```

But this throws an `com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: database`

I hope here is somebody who can help me!

Comment: Are you using plain eureka or spring cloud Netflix eureka?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero I am using spring cloud netflix eureka

Comment: Sure, then help me out here. Where did you declare this `@Bean EurekaInstanceConfigBean`? and what are you trying to do with that?

Comment: @MarcosBarbero I declare it in my AppConfig file on the clients. The  Application runs in an docker image in ecs. So the Client is able to register at the Discovery, but the client transmit the ip inside the image and not the ip where the image runs.

Comment: Hi @Jocasso did you made it? At the beggining of this year I was with the same problem, for some reason Eureka registers every service with the private IP address of the containers, so when they try to reach together they can't connect, I mean, they find the way to talk but they can talk because of the private IPs.

Comment: @Jocasso did you solve this issue? I am facing the same right now, please help!

Answer (score 2):

You can try this steps, this explains how to deploy Eureka on AWS Fargate as containers.
https://karthikeayan.github.io/post/netflix-eureka-on-aws-fargate/

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments, there are a couple of things that you can do.

First, as you are running inside a docker container you don't need to declare this `@Bean`, it can be replaced with the following configuration properties:

```
eureka:
  instance:
    non-secure-port: 8090
    prefer-ip-address: true
```

To pick up the right IP address you have to configure [some network interfaces to be ignored](https://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-static/spring-cloud.html#ignore-network-interfaces), it can be achieved by adding the following:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    inetutils:
      ignoredInterfaces:
        - docker0
        - veth.*
```

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, sadly it doesn't work for me. I get   "status 401 reading DatabaseClient#getPropertiesBySearch(Property)"  back

Comment: What's `DatabaseClient`?

Comment: I called the interface DatabaseClient. It is the interface for a @FeignClient

Comment: But what's the error? 401 means you are not authorized to perform a request

Comment: I don't know. I only get the error if i am using your confidurations. The client have basic auth enabled but i config the access with BasicAuthRequestInterceptor

Comment: Then your problem is on your authentication not on the routing anymore. The 401 status means you could reach the application, but you're not authorized to perform the request.
It's a different problem than your original question.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few ways to about this, but one way that I've solved this was to create a bean post processor that intercepts the EurekaInstanceConfigBean during the postProcessAfterInitialization lifecycle hook.

You can obtain the Fargate instance's IP address by using InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress(). Once the bean is determined to be an instance of EurekaInstanceConfigBean, you can set the instanceId, ipAddress, hostname, statusPageUrl, and healthCheckUrl using the obtained Fargate private IP.

So long as all of your services are running within the same VPC, you should be able to have services register correctly with Eureka using addresses that can be used for inter-service communicate.

Edit (adding snippet):

```java
@Component
@Profile("dev")
public class EurekaInstanceConfigBeanPostProcessor implements BeanPostProcessor {

    private static final Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(EurekaInstanceConfigBeanPostProcessor.class);

    @Value("${spring.application.name}")
    private String serviceName;

    @Value("${server.port}")
    private int port;

    private String fargateIp;

    {
        try {
            fargateIp = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostAddress();
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            LOGGER.warn("Could not get the Fargate instance ip address.");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object postProcessAfterInitialization(Object bean, String beanName) {

        if (bean instanceof EurekaInstanceConfigBean) {
            LOGGER.info("EurekaInstanceConfigBean detected. Setting IP address to {}", fargateIp);
            EurekaInstanceConfigBean instanceConfigBean = ((EurekaInstanceConfigBean) bean);
            instanceConfigBean.setInstanceId(fargateIp + ":" + serviceName + ":" + port);
            instanceConfigBean.setIpAddress(fargateIp);
            instanceConfigBean.setHostname(fargateIp);
            instanceConfigBean.setStatusPageUrl("http://" + fargateIp + ":" + port + "/actuator/info");
            instanceConfigBean.setHealthCheckUrl("http://" + fargateIp + ":" + port + "/actuator/health");
        }

        return bean;
    }

}
```